# strictly monotonic roots in constructive analysis

Tags: real-analysis, exponentiation, constructive-mathematics, monotone-functions

I'm working on the definition of real numbers from “Real Analysis: A Constructive Approach” by Mark Bridger. Several examples require to prove that powers and roots are monotonic.

I proved $\forall n\geq 1\, \forall a>0\, \forall b>0\, (a^n\leq b^n\to a\leq b)$ from $\forall n\geq 1\, \forall a>0\, \forall b>0\, (a<b\to a^n<b^n)$ using the definition $a\leq b := \lnot a>b$.

I don't know how to prove $\forall n\geq 1\, \forall a>0\, \forall b>0\, (a^n<b^n\to a<b)$. Is it even possible without going down to rational intervals?

Comment: I don't know the definitions in Bridger's book, but $x < y$ should be an existential statement "under the hood" - it should say there is a pair of approximations of $x$ and $y$ that show that $x$ has to be less than $y$, e.g. the upper estimate for $x$ is less than the lower estimate of $y$ under those approximations. So, given that kind of evidence showing that $x^n < y^n$, it should be possible to effectively convert it to show that $x < y$. In other words, if you have a rational $r$ such that $0 < r < y^n - x^n$, you should be able to construct a rational $r'$ with $0  < r' < y-x$.

Comment: Can you use $b^n-a^n=(b-a)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+…+b^{n-1})$ and then that the second factor is positive?

Comment: I just want to note that the case $n=1$ is a tautology, so you can reduce the problem to the case of $n>1$. It looks like LutzL's comment is the correct answer -- you might be able to prove it using induction. Also, are $a$ and $b$ here assumed to be denote real numbers or rational numbers?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are reals, $n$ is natural.

Comment: @LutzL, I think you can make your comment into an answer. Bridger's contains necessary theorems: multiplication and positivity by Proposition 1.5.14, strict order is translation-invariant by Corollary 1.5.8.3, the multiplicative inverse is defined on positive numbers by Proposition 1.3.21, ring axioms by Proposition 1.2.18, strict order axioms by Proposition 1.2.20 and Proposition 1.2.21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As algebraically
$$
b^n-a^n=(b-a)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+…+b^{n-1})
$$
and with $a,b$ positive the second factor on the right is also positive, $b^n-a^n$ and $b-a$ will always have the same sign.